# draw candlesticks(matploblit)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pylab import *
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick
from datetime import datetime


data2 = [(datetime(2012, 2, 1), 3103, 3102.01, 3103.62, 3101.90),
      (datetime(2012, 2, 1), 3102, 3102.90, 3103.16, 3102.09),
      (datetime(2012, 2, 2), 3100.89, 3102.59, 3102.86, 3100.51),
      (datetime(2012, 2, 3), 3103.62, 3102.01, 3103.62, 3101.90),
      (datetime(2012, 2, 5), 3102.24, 3102.90, 3103.16, 3102.09),
      (datetime(2012, 2, 6), 3100.89, 3102.59, 3102.86, 3100.51)]

quotes = [(date2num(item[0]),) + item[1:] for item in data2]

fig = figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mondays)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)

candlestick(ax, quotes, width=0.6)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
setp( gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')

show()
```

This works well and draws a candlestick graph. This seems to conflict with `read_command_line(prog_args_array)`:

```
def read_command_line(prog_args_array):
    prog = prog_args_array.pop(0)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__, prog=prog)
    parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version=VERSION)  
    return parser.parse_args(prog_args_array)

def main(prog_args_array):
    args = read_command_line(prog_args_array)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

which gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tdseq4.py", line 124, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./tdseq4.py", line 89, in main
    fig = figure()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1683, in __init__
    baseName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it not in your data it is in loading the backend.
If you are call

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print plt.get_backend()
```

it will show I you are using Tkinter

You need to look at how you are invoking your `.py` file and try it from a interactive shell.

since tkinter is only looking for sys.argv[0] you can put `import sys;print sys.argv` to see how your arguments look

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you modify sys.argv, which causes problems.  This can be solved with:

```
def read_command_line(prog_args_array):
    prog = prog_args_array[0]
    (…)
```

(instead of using `pop(0)`, which in effect modifies `sys.argv`).